# How to implement __repr__ for a C# class to be used in python.net?

Tags: c#, python, .net, python.net, pythonnet

I have `pythonnet` v 2.3.0 installed. I have a C# class library which I use in Python. I have a `Point` class (a code snippet):

```
public Point(double x, double y)
{
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

public override string ToString()
{
    return $"Point({x}, {y})";
}
```

When I work with this class library in Python (in Python shell):

```
>>> p1 = Point(10,15)
>>> p1
<Geometry.Point object at 0x000000000558F828>
>>> str(p1)
'Point(10, 15)'
```

Because I override the `ToString()`, when I run `str(p1)` I see my custom view of the object. However, when I just access a variable `p1`, then it goes to the `__repr__()` method under the hood which gives me ugly `<Geometry.Point object at 0x000000000558F828>`.

Is there a method in C# class that is possible to override so that `pythonnet` would use that method when getting the `__repr__`?

https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/issues/680

Comment: Check out their repository. A search for "repr" shows that you **may** (I'm guessing) be able to define a static method in your type with the following signature: `pulic static IntPtr tp_repr(IntPtr ob)`. Some of their implementations had to specify the `new` modifier as well. https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/search?utf8=✓&q=Repr&type=

Comment: My guess would be: `public static IntPtr tp_repr(IntPtr ob)  { var self = (Point)GetManagedObject(ob);  return Runtime.PyString_FromString($"Point({self.x}, {self.y})"); }` Please understand this is entirely a guess. I've never used this Library before and only spent a few minutes reviewing the source after not finding anything in their docs

Comment: Ugh... Looking further it looks like some of those methods are internal to the library. Though I think it might be a fair starting point for you to look through their code base and see if you can find something that *can* be used. I'm still fairly confident you need to include that static method

Comment: @pinkfloydx33, thanks will dig deeper. I think `IntPtr` is used only for representation of integers, are you sure this can be used for custom classes? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: IntPtr has nothing to do with integers necessarily. It can represent just about anything. It's used for interop between managed and unmanaged code